# How to stop asp.net page reload when selecting a jquery dialog?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

[image: dialog]

I use jquery ui dialog to display the various forms like customer, products etc. Its done by displaying the aspx page inside an iframe which is inside another div and showing this div as the dialog. This structure below is created dynamically.

```
<div id="Div1" runat="server" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="customer"></a>
                <div>
                    <iframe id="frame_customer"></iframe>
                </div>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a id="product"> </a>

                <div>
                    <iframe id="frame_product"></iframe>
                </div>
         </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

The jquery for showing it as a pop up is as below:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("a").each(function () {
            $.data(this, 'dialog',
              $(this).next("div").dialog({
                  resizable: false,
                  autoOpen: false,
                  modal: false,
                  title: this.id,
                  width: 900,
                  height: 590,
                  position: ['middle', 150],
                  draggable: true,
                  open: function (event, ui) {
                      $(this).parent().children().children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                  },

                  buttons: {
                      "Exit": function () {
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                      }
                  },
              })
            );
        }).click(function (event) {
            $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('frame_' + this.id).src = this.id + '.aspx';
            return false;
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("iframe").attr("scrolling", "no");
        $("iframe").attr("frameborder", "0");
    });

</script>
```

Now, my problem is that, whenever I select another dialog by clicking, the previous form gets refreshed and I loose all changes and selections on this form. So how can I stop postback when switching between the forms?

The rendered HTML is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        DiaryGold
    </title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="Scripts/themes/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Scripts/themes/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Scripts/themes/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Scripts/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/style.css" type="text/css" />

    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url('images/AppBG.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: #0b0535;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: 99%;
        }

        html {
            height: 100%;
        }


        .header {
            position: relative;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            color: #d8e8ff;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .header h1 {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                color: #BF0413;
                border: none;
                line-height: 42px;
                font-size: 42px;
                display: inline;
            }

        .main {
            padding: 0px 12px;
            margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
            min-height: 800px;
        }

        .framestyle {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #d8e8ff;
        }


        #header {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }


        .center {
            display: table;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 10;
        }

        .menu {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 32px;
            background-color: #383838;
        }

        div {
            opacity: 0.95;
        }

        .ui-widget-content {
            border: 1px solid darkgray;
            background: none;
            color: #2c4359;
        }

        .ui-front {
            z-index: 1 !important;
        }
    </style>


    <script>


        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("a").each(function () {
                $.data(this, 'dialog',
                  $(this).next("div").dialog({
                      resizable: false,
                      autoOpen: false,
                      modal: false,
                      title: this.id,
                      width: 900,
                      height: 590,

                      position: ['middle', 150],
                      draggable: true,
                      open: function (event, ui) {
                          $(this).parent().children().children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                      },

                      buttons: {
                          "Exit": function () {
                              $(this).dialog("close");
                          }
                      }
                  })

                );

            }).click(function (event) {
                if (this.id != '#') {
                    $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');
                    document.getElementById('frame_' + this.id).src = this.id + '.aspx';
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("iframe").attr("scrolling", "no");
            $("iframe").attr("frameborder", "0");
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="center">

        <div id="menu1" class="menu">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li>
                    <a id="#">Log Samples</a>
                    <div id="#"><iframe class="framestyle" id="frame_#"></iframe> </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a id="#">Commercial</a>
                            <div id="#"><iframe class="framestyle" id="frame_#"></iframe> </div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a id="LogSamples">Log Samples</a>
                                    <div id="LogSamples"><iframe class="framestyle" id="frame_LogSamples"></iframe> </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a id="Customers">Customers</a>
                                    <div id="Customers"><iframe class="framestyle" id="frame_Customers"></iframe> </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <li>
                    <a id="#">Admin</a>
                    <div id="#"><iframe class="framestyle" id="frame_#"></iframe> </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a id="LabUsers">Lab Users</a>
                            <div id="LabUsers"><iframe class="framestyle" id="frame_LabUsers"></iframe> </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="LabRoles">Lab Roles</a>
                            <div id="LabRoles"><iframe class="framestyle" id="frame_LabRoles"></iframe> </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="ScreenForRoles">ScreenForRoles</a>
                            <div id="ScreenForRoles"><iframe class="framestyle" id="frame_ScreenForRoles"></iframe> </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="header">
        <div style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="MainTitle" style="position: relative; float: right;">
                <img src="images/diarygold-logo.gif" height="65" />
            </div>
            <div class="MainTitle" style="position: relative; float: left; vertical-align: central; line-height: 80px; margin-top: 25px;">

                <img alt="" class="auto-style1" src="images/LIMSLogo.png" height="40" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might be calling any method on `Page_Load` which clears the data. Check the `Page_Load` once.

Comment: I see you're using both event.preventDefault() and return false. Both do the same thing, so it's kind of overkill.

Comment: Are the Exit buttons asp elements inside of forms? If they are, then they will cause a postback, and you can avoid this by replacing them with html elements. If that doesn't work, then show us the code in the asp pages that are opening in the iframes if y0ou would. Your problem is probably in there.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to open up multiple customer dialogs?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Yes, exactly, I want the user to open multiple dialogs at the same time...

Comment: You are probably running into `id` collisions. Does `Div1` have multiple `<iframe id="frame_customer">` then?

Comment: As in `document.getElementById('frame_' + this.id).src` will always be pointing to the same iframe.

Comment: @Mike I create the iframes dynamically and give it a dynamic name. that means there will be frame_customer, frame_products etc

Comment: @Mike : I have hardcoded it in the example. I am reading the menu from the database table depending on the users roles and then build the html using stringbuilder to create the structure as shwon

Comment: I don't see how your code would work for multiple customer frames though. Perhaps include a version of the rendered html for multiple customers or multiple products.

Comment: @Mike: I have included the rendered html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48818/discussion-between-sony-and-mikesmithdev)

Comment: after chatting, I couldn't replicate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some [research](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-prevent-iframe-reload-in-dialog-on-focus), it seems this is a bug on the jQuery UI library.

Notice in this [first demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sKJmU/) that the version is 1.10.X (`<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>` on the top right pane) and causes the same behavior you're experiencing (it will not load the iframe, but you'll see the effect on the browser loading icon).

However on this [second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LuAhj/) it's using version 1.8.X (fiddle's version) and it's not causing the refresh.

If you're using latest version, try to downgrade to version 1.8.X and see if solves the problem. If it does, open a jQuery UI ticket bug to the guys on jQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much... that was a bug in 1.9.1 . I changed to 1.8.3 and its working very well. I have been researching many weeks about this issue and finally its sorted... I am so grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `iframe`'s are inside the `a`'s. This will cause the `a`'s click event to fire. To fix this I would suggest putting the `iframe`'s outside of the `a`'s.

If you cannot, a simple addition to your JS should do it...

```
$("a").each(function () {
    $.data(this, 'dialog',
      $(this).next("div").dialog({
          resizable: false,
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: false,
          title: this.id,
          width: 900,
          height: 590,
          position: ['middle', 150],
          draggable: true,
          open: function (event, ui) {
              $(this).parent().children().children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
          },

          buttons: {
              "Exit": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          },
       })
    );

    // stop the click event from moving up the chain
    $('#frame_' + this.id).click(function(event) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

}).click(function (event) {
    $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('frame_' + this.id).src = this.id + '.aspx';
});
```

Comment: Actually, the frames are outside the a tag, I put it wrong in my question... I tried the second option, but not working...

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your approach. Consider just using divs instead of the iframe. You can load the div using jQuery's load command:  $(this).next("div").load(this.id+".aspx");

Of course, you'll need to pare your customer.aspx and product.aspx pages down to just the form and it's contents.

Here is some sample code:

```
$(this).next("div").load(this.id+".aspx", function() {
   // this is now the div
   $('form',this).submit(function(e) {
       // validate here (this is the form)
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax($(this).attr("action"),$(this).serialize());
       // close the dialog here
   });
});
```